# Micro:bit serial pins

Tags: bbc-microbit, nrf51

I'm looking to port some C++ code to the micro:bit and I would like to use the USB-UART capabilities of the board.

My current project uses the nrfx library to set up peripherals such as the UART. I need to know which GPIO are connected to the *interface mcu* that is providing the USB-UART bridge. I have found the list of pins exposed on the [edge connector](https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal/blob/master/inc/drivers/MicroBitPin.h) but they don't include the pins routed to other peripherals.

The [microbit-dal](https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal) describes the [MicroBitSerial class](https://github.com/lancaster-university/microbit-dal/blob/602153e9199c28c08fd2561ce7b43bf64e9e7394/inc/drivers/MicroBitSerial.h#L221) but it does not mention which pins are routed to the *interface mcu*.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a project where the pin names for the [microbit-dal are mapped to the MCU pin](https://gitlab.uwe.ac.uk/i2-naish/microbit-challenge-3/-/blob/269471c8911a44d9b248be15350c42b43542fce6/microbit-reciever/microbit/microbit-dal/mbed-dev-bin/TARGET_NRF51_MICROBIT/TARGET_NORDIC/TARGET_MCU_NRF51822/TARGET_NRF51_MICROBIT/PinNames.h).

```
    // RX AND TX PINS
    TGT_TX = p24,
    TGT_RX = p25,
    ...
    RX_PIN_NUMBER = TGT_RX,
    TX_PIN_NUMBER = TGT_TX,
```

The pin numbers are correct and I was able to port my project to the microbit. The UART is available through the interface MCU.